# How to create an SSIS package to import flat file and schedule it to run as an SQL job?

Tags: sql, ssis

does anyone know really good step by step tutorial to create a package to import tab delimited flat file into a table using SSIS and then schedule it to run as an SQL job at specified time?

Or maybe someone can show me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get started with SSIS is, using Management Studio, right click on the database you want to import into, under Tasks, select Import data. This kicks off a wizard which is quite straight forward. At the end of the wizard, you have the option to save the package to the server or to a file. If you save it to a file, you can then create a job and set the step type to be `Sql Server Integration Services Package`. You can then configure the parts of your package and schedule the job as normal.

Comment: if I have each day a new file but with the same structure can I reuse package and not create a new one each time?

Comment: If you overwrite the existing file with the same file name, the same package can be used. If you need to preserve the existing file, you could always add a second step to the job to rename it, or copy it somewhere else.

Comment: So I have created ssis package not sure how to add it as a step?

Comment: Assuming you have a job created, in the properties window, on the right hand side, there is a list of items, one of which is `Steps`. Click this and you will see the steps for the current job. At the bottom of the window should be a `New` button to add a new step. The type is specified in this wizard, and you will notice that the wizard changes when you select the SSIS type.

Comment: @Manres - how did you get on?